# Is "recommend deletion" secretly a vote to delete?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-delete

There's a [rumor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5033/14366) (attributed to Shog9 but not verifiable by me) that

> If six users without the ability to delete "recommend deletion", the post will also be automatically deleted.

If this is true, I find it worrisome. It creates a parallel vote-to-delete that users between 2000 and 20,000 rep can vote in, even if some of these users are not even trusted to vote to close.

What's more, these users are presented with the choice in a way that stongly encourages them to vote for deletion, in that the only alternatives (apart from "don't know") is "looks good" and "edit it to look good". This suggests to users that if they understand the question and the answer (and so "don't know" is not right), there is no middle ground between answers that "look good" (or can be made to do so) and answers that ought to be deleted. In effect the UI is suggesting that unless the user would upvote the answer, he should vote for deletion -- even though the vote is presented to him as a "recommendation".

It feels very backwards to encourage users to vote to delete by making it free, whereas merely downvoting an answer costs 1 rep.

At least at Math.SE we have a significant population of answers that are not *good* answers, but nevertheless shouldn't be deleted -- downvotes are the right way to deal with them. These answers are often short enough to trigger the low-quality filter. Their major characteristic is that they often embody the first instinctive reaction of somebody looking at the question, but are actually wrong for subtle reasons explained in comments or other answers. Having them stay visible but downvoted conveys valuable information to the reader, namely that this intuitively "obvious" answer is in fact wrong. Deleting them would entail a loss in usefulness.

If the secret parallel deletion vote is real, I think that

- It should be made much more obvious to the user casting the "recommendation" that such a recommendation is in fact a vote that will cause *automatic* deletion without being reviewed by a moderator or high-rep user.
- The review interface **really** should provide a middle way between *"looks good, I will upvote"* and *"burn it with fire!"*, such as "no action is needed" or "downvoting is good enough for this".

Comment: So are you saying that `suggest delete` shouldn't actually delete the post, but just put it in another queue for >20k rep users & dimonds to actually delete, or are you suggesting the UI be updated such that <20k users are not encouraged to make bad decisions (or both)?

Comment: It's worth noting that 'looks good' is actually saying, exactly, "no action is needed".  So really you're just asking to change the wording of the button, not make a new one.

Comment: @Servy: That may well be the _effect_ of pressing "looks good", but that is not the _impression_ a relatively inexperienced user will get. So yes, changing the wording on the button would also be a way to satisfy my concerns about the "missing middle way".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Which is why I feel it's not so much of a problem of the tool, but that the tool needs a good tutorial describing under what circumstances you should do each of the available options.  You could possibly fix a bit by re-wording buttons or something like that, but at the end of the day it's a user training issue more than a programming/UI issue.

Comment: @Servy: It still worries me that people who are not even trusted to _close_ questions (resulting in a state from which mistakes are fairly easily discoverable and fixable) are now being trusted to _delete_ questions -- which is very hard to discover and fix for other users, unless somebody happens across the deleted question in the short window of time it is one of the three last deletions shown in the 20k+ moderator tools.

Comment: That brings me back to my first question.  Are you suggesting that <20k users not be able to delete, or that the UI be updated to ensure they do it right?  Half of your comments indicate one, half the other.

Comment: @Servy: I'm suggesting that **if** <20k users are able to delete, **then** at least they should be made clearly aware that their votes-to-delete are actually votes that will be automatically tallied **and** that it is okay to vote to preserve a wrong answer. That would be a minimum to satisfy me. But of course entirely eliminating the feature would also satisfy my concerns.

Comment: @Henning: these don't really behave the same way that "votes" do elsewhere. They definitely don't behave the same way that *actual* delete votes do. And frankly, I'm not sure how much more clear we can make it - if folks are clicking "recommend deletion" on stuff *they don't believe should be deleted*, then I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @Shog9: The point is that _neither_ "Looks good" nor "recommend deletion" feels like the right thing to do for the posts I'm talking about. And since these are the only options (apart from "not sure") it is easy to get the impression that one _should_ be recommending deletion for everything that doesn't "look good".

Comment: @HenningMakholm As an inexperienced user, I have encountered exactly the problem you highlight here (which is why I find myself here on the meta). My first experience with the review system is clicking the "Not sure" button an awful lot. Close to 100% of the low quality answers I have reviewed do not "look good" but neither are they worthy of deletion. I needed to read your question before I understood how to use the system correctly, so thank you for indirectly documenting it.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbach Is that a bad thing? If you are an inexperienced user, then I assume it's expected that you won't be sure a lot. No one says you need to go into the review queue and start swinging the ban hammer. But going in there and taking action on things you know what to do is still a worthwhile effort!

Comment: @corsiKa If there is ambiguity (and I suggest there is), then it could just as well work out that inexperienced users will choose arbitrarily between "looks good", "not sure" and "recommend for deletion". That would be bad. Henning's suggested "no action required" button is *exactly* what I was wishing for when I got started reviewing. Probably other newbie reviewers are looking for that button too.

Comment: @gnat can you please explain why it's a duplicate?

Comment: @ShadowWizard duplicate question officially explains how exactly and vhen “recommend deletion” serves as vote to delete

Comment: @gnat true, but it explains **new rules**, while this one here is about how it used to be and still useful as it stands. Closing old question as dupe of a newer question is proper sometimes, but as far as I can tell, not in this case.

Comment: @ShadowWizard to me it looks like the case here. Per my reading, newer question covers same rules as explained in answer here: "sufficient number of delete recommendations (currently 6) will cause the post to be deleted immediately... the post has to first end up in the queue" and explains how new queue (LQ) _inherits_ these rules from old one (10K)

Answer (score 34):

Yes, a sufficient number of delete recommendations (currently 6 on most sites, 4 on Stack Overflow) will cause the post to be deleted immediately, provided it has zero or negative score. (If it has a positive score, it will raise an automatic moderator flag instead.)

Why these numbers? They were chosen based on the data... And on most sites it also matches the number of spam or offensive flags needed to automatically delete a post. Note that unlike spam/"rude or abusive" flags, delete recommendations do not automatically confer a down-vote on the post, or a penalty upon deletion.

Why offer automatic deletion at all? Because requiring a moderator or three 20K users to delete a post that has been reviewed multiple times and universally seen as undesirable is a waste.

Note that in order for this to even be *possible*, the post has to first end up in the queue - either because the automated quality-check found it lacking, or because it was flagged as "very low quality" or "not an answer". You can't just pick an arbitrary answer - even one that's been down-voted - and "recommend deletion" on it. Also, answers can't go to the queue multiple times, so if a flag is cast after it has already been reviewed, that flag will go to moderators instead.

Comment: But at least users who flag for spam/offensive makes an active decision to try to get the post deleted. The review system presents ordinary users with a forced choice that very stongly suggest that unless the user can certify that the post "looks good", he is _supposed to_ "recommend deletion". That wording is seriously misleading if "looks good" is intended to merely mean "does not deserve to be deleted".

Comment: Can normal delete votes be counted towards that 6? For example, it doesn't make much sense that [this is still sitting in the review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/8885). Surely my "delete" vote counts at least as much as a "recommend deletion" vote no?

Comment: Good catch, @Mysticial - we'll be checking delete *and* recommend-delete responses in the future.

Comment: @Shog9 You could even weight it. Since it takes either 6 "recommend delete" or 3 delete votes, it might make just as much sense to count a delete vote as 2 points and use a fixed threshold of 6.

Comment: That sounds overly-complex - let's just say that six delete-reviews or 3 delete-votes will nix an answer.

Comment: If the button actually deletes it has to be named "vote to delete", or simply "delete". Talking about "recommend" is seriously misleading, it implies that the recommendation would be checked by someone who knows what they are doing, but this isn't the case.

Comment: We have a button labelled "close" and some folks *still* think that's a recommendation, @sth. Much more concerning to me is the notion that folks are recommending actions they don't actually believe should happen.

Comment: I guess this changed since the [Let's get ride of the 10K flag queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/209901), right?  For example here we have 6 deletion votes but wasn't deleted at the end: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4990123

Comment: Didn't really change much, @fedorqui - only moderators can delete upvoted answers. However, as part of that change a moderator flag is raised when review sez delete, so it's less ineffective than it was before. That question was already closed anyway, but... I did some... stuff... to it.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a ton, @Shog9 for the explanation and for the... stuff :)

Comment: This doesn't apply to questions, through.

Answer (score 27):

I don't think anything is wrong with the system insofar as we are discussing here, except for one thing; I do think that it could be useful for the `Looks Good` button to instead be titled, for example, `Don't Delete`.

I think `Don't Delete` gets across the point neatly: You aren't saying the post is "stellar" or even 'good', but you are saying that you don't wish it to be deleted.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is a bad thing at all. A huge part of the new review system is to allow more *community moderation*. If *six, count 'em six* users happen to agree that a post, *already marked as probably low quality* should be deleted, I think it should be deleted.

Sure, the "parallel systems" bit makes it a bit complicated, but it's really quite transparent to the user. If you think it should be deleted, you press that button. If a bunch of people agree and no one disagrees, it gets deleted. That seems like *exactly* how content should be deleted. It's important to keep in mind that these are posts *already* algorythmically identified as likely crap, and a few Looks Good votes is all it takes to remove an item from the queue (and thus no more Recommend Deletion votes can happen).

Why shouldn't it cost rep? Well, why should it? Why should cleaning up low quality, extremely brief posts hurt *me*? Downvotes cost rep because it's marking a post as incorrect; downvoting is different from *cleaning up garbage*. If you penalize users for cleaning up garbage you're going to start finding a lot more garbage than people willing to clean it up.

> The review interface really should provide a middle way between "looks good, I will upvote" and "burn it with fire!", such as "no action is needed" or "downvoting is good enough for this".

No. The low quality review system is not about voting; that's why there's no voting buttons. The post is either acceptable as a post on the site (Looks Good or Edit) or it's not (Recommend/vote for deletion). You can vote if you feel strongly afterwards, but voting isn't part of the workflow for a reason.

Comment: I don't particularly care if downvoting is _part of the workflow_ or not, but there **should** be a clearly visible way to say "this is a bad answer, but in a way that the ordinary voting system is better at handling than deletion would be" --- that is, _does not look good, but should not be deleted either_.

Comment: You seem to be saying that anything that does not **look good** is automatically garbage that should be deleted. I most emphatically disagree with that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm there is. That's what the "looks good" button is for. You seem to completely misunderstand my point and the general use of the interface.

Comment: Also you seem to assume that whichever automation used to place the _already marked as probably low quality_ is necessarily right. I have seen it err again and again. It would be a **tremendous** loss for the site if everything its feeble little digital mind cannot see the value in would be deleted, unless it actively "looks good" to enough users to stop the system from campaigning to be deleted (how many users are that, anyway?).

Comment: (atsign preserver text here) @BenBrocka: Are you seriously claiming that the average user would consider a button reading "looks good" to be for "questions that **don't actually look good** but look bad in a way that should be dealt with by voting on the post rather than by deleting it"????

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't assume it's automatically right, but it's an extreme limiting factor, AND it's not being used automatically; it requires *six* people with a fair amount of rep to all agree, *before* other people mark the post as "looks good". That is a VERY narrow window that most assuredly means "this is not a good post and should really be deleted"

Comment: This is turning not constructive fast. "Looks good" means "don't delete; this is an answer". That's it.

Comment: (atsign prserver) @BenBrocka: The average user will assume that the text "Looks good" is intended to be interpreted according to its meaning in the English language, which is manifestly different from the meaning you claim for it. No matter how much you write "that's it" afterwards.

Comment: (atsign preserver) @BenBrocka: The window is gaping wide when those fairly low rep users (2000+) are being asked to decide between "looks good" and "delete", and are not being told that they are supposed to click "looks good" for every question that does not deserve deletion, no matter whether it in fact looks good to them or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm By that same logic, users also know that they shouldn't be clicking delete for an answer just because it's factually wrong, as long as it doesn't meet any of the delete reasons provided.  If they don't think it 'looks good' and know that they shouldn't delete it, they will be forced to either 'not sure' it, or come to meta and figure out what they should do (which would be click 'looks good').  You assume that the default action, if they don't know what to do is to click delete.  You need to prove that assertion.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not hypothesizing -- this is due to a concrete event at Math.SE where a user had clicked "delete" for at least one justifiably-downvoted-but-deserving-of-existing answer, because he (entirely correctly) didn't think it "looked good" and interpreted the selection of options in the UI as guidance that everything that doesn't looks good deserves to be deleted.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well then it's a good thing that you need 6 votes to delete, not just one.  No matter how good your UI is, or what requirements you have for people to be able to use the tool, some people will make wrong decisions (either as mistakes, due to lack of understanding, or maliciously).  The system is designed to deal with that.  The fact that one person did the wrong thing for one post isn't evidence that the entire review system shouldn't exist.

Comment: @Servy: When the system directly encourages the misunderstanding (by presenting the user with a forced choice between "looks good" and "delete"), then I don't think "designed to deal with that" is a reasonable description of it.

Comment: So do you have evidence that lots of people are having this problem over extended periods of time?  My guess is that it's something the people first using the review system will have problems with (which will always be the case), but very quickly they will learn what is appropriate.  Because of the votes required for an action to be taken, there shouldn't be any significant negative consequences as a result of mistakes during this "learning period".

Comment: @Servy: Can you propose a realistic mechanism by which users will "very quickly learn what is appropriate"? I cannot see any. The learning period until a user learns (by chance? or what) that "looks good" does not actually mean "looks good" but instead means "may be good or bad, but is not something that should be deleted" may well be infinite.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, one of the best mechanisms for learning what to do in any of the review queues is seeing what other people have done for a given question; it's a pretty good way to learn the system.  When they vote to delete a question that is only wrong, and not bad, and see that several other people choose 'looks good' it will indicate that they're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Servy: That mechanism could just as well serve to propagate a collective delusion that "looks good" actually means "looks good".

Comment: @HenningMakholm And yet there are really only a small number of highly active users, most of which are active on meta and take the time to properly understand the tools that they are using, so new users are highly likely to see more of their votes.  Additionally, if the devs/moderators/active users notice a significant number of problematic decisions they will bring it up and address it in some other manor.  Currently it appears that you're just afraid that this might become a problem in the future, rather than asserting it's a problem now.  (You lack evidence to make this assertion.)