# Could we have a feature to convert answers into comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges, vote-to-delete

This feature is currently moderator exclusive. Could we allow delete-privileged users convert answers into comments?

What I imagine, is that a user votes to delete an answer, **a lightbox comes up (much like when closing), which allows the user to pick a reason for deleting**. I.e.:

- This answer is actually a comment.
- This answer is an entirely different question.
- This answer is spam.
- No comment

And allow the user to pick one.

If 2 (out of the 3) votes are of the same kind, treat it as the appropriately selected option. (actually a comment => transfer to comment on the question, spam => -100 reputation, etc).

Could use a bit of tweaking, but that's what I have in mind.

Your penny?

Comment: Makes sense. Allow delete privileged users to maintain potentially useful content rather than deleting it outright. It's actually less harsh then allowing delete only. What's the point of the _"entirely different question"_ option though?

Comment: Can you also allow people to convert comments into an answer if it's correct? Vote-Down happens like a deadly virus to new comers, when we can only answer and can't comment constructively/usefully. I really do not mind not being able to answer as long as we can comment - and the comment can be voted up or converted into an answer!



Thanks.

Comment: One of other users happened to noticed this:-
Please see this post: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast

It is saying, down-vote and comment strategically! Well who has the ability to down-vote? Users with 125 or more. And why would they want to down-vote to earn more? As if reputation was money or something to compete for. It seems like people down-vote for fun and there's no reason, nothing.

Really do not understand why people want to push one down to earn what they deserve!

Thanks.

Comment: This would be a very useful feature, and I think we should work it in the review queues for users with 2000+ rep, similarly to how the ["recommend deletion" thingy works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145287/is-recommend-deletion-secretly-a-vote-to-delete). A lot of "low quality" answers could be turned into comments instead of being deleted (6 delete recommendations will automatically delete the answer).