# What are the criteria for deleting/keeping a Low Quality Post?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

I searched and searched and I couldn't find the criteria for deletion/keeping of LQPs. What are the criteria for keeping or deleting a LQP? Usually in my experience it takes 6 Recommend Deletions, but in some cases I recommended deletion and that was the only thing the post needed to be deleted.

[image: img2] (Attempt to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296043) :D)

Also, I found something else.

> > [image: img]

That doesn't seem right. A single person said the post looked good (against 5 people who didn't!) and the answer was not deleted. Why is that?

My current guess:

- 1 "Looks Good" means it's kept (NOT a good idea IMO)
- 6 "Recommend Deletion" for it to be deleted
- If [the magical power of unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328) is with the voter, 1 "Recommend Deletion" for it to be deleted

Comment: I can't find the reference post, but AFAIK it takes 3 *delete* votes to delete a post. "Recommend deletion" votes just make the posts more visible to users who can cast delete votes (20k users).

Comment: Well, I was wrong. 6 recommend deletion votes do cause a deletion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/167534