# Why was this answer not deleted at the sixth Recommend Deletion vote?

Tags: support, review, low-quality-posts, deleted-posts

The [last I heard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145287/is-recommend-deletion-secretly-a-vote-to-delete/145292#145292), if an answer in the Low Quality Posts review queue gets six Recommend Deletion posts, it gets deleted immediately, and the post is marked simply as 'deleted on ...', such as [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/138354) (physics 10k+ or SE team only).

However, I'm a bit confused by [this review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/138435) (again physics 10k+ or SE team only):

> [image]

The post got six Recommend Deletion votes, which should have deleted it on the spot, but it lingered on for another hour until a moderator deleted it (and turned it into a comment). Do `Looks OK` votes somehow count against recommended deletions? (My understanding was that they do, but only regarding whether the post stays on the queue or gets taken off it.) If so, does the existing documentation, such as the linked post above, need to be clarified on this regard?

---

Edit:

Answer revision history and timeline as requested:

> [image]

---

> [image]

In the other example, the timeline and revision history both say 'post deleted from review' attributing it to the reviewers.

Comment: It wasn't the accepted answer?

Comment: No, accepted answer was separate. It does have score +1-0, but that shouldn't stop Shog9's post from applying if I understand it correctly.

Comment: What do you see in the revision history of that answer?

Comment: @nicael see edited question.

Comment: Ordinary users can't delete an answer with positive score. Even 1000 "recommend deletion" votes won't auto delete the answer. Only a moderator can delete.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, that sounds reasonable. Is this clearly documented somewhere? It feels like the linked post should have that caveat just for clarity.

Comment: It's documented in the faq: "this will prioritize the review task for others who can vote to delete, and if a sufficient number of reviewers all recommend deletion (as of March 2014, the number is six) it can cause the post to be either deleted (if the score is less than or equal to 0) or forwarded to moderators for further review".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks.