Display the reason for review invalidation in timeline's comment
For more transparency on review invalidations, in the post's timeline, can the "comment" column on the line of the invalidation contain the reason for the invalidation instead of being empty?
For reference, this answer lists the reasons a review task can become "completed" or "invalidated". Currently, completed reviews have the review's results in the "comment" column (for example : "Looks OK × 3, Recommend Deletion × 2").

The reason's always going to be "not enough delete votes" when it's a low quality review. That's all you can really do with those. You can click on it to see what happened if you really want.

@RobertLongson For example if you take this review (the latest one in the timeline with 2 invalidations I linked) it was invalidated because (I'm almost sure) a mod took action on the flag (I'm confident with this reason because the flag was mine and it got declined at the same time the review task got invalidated and the invalidation time doesn't match any of the review's time)

No, you'd see the moderator vote to delete. Per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145287/is-recommend-deletion-secretly-a-vote-to-delete you need 4 recommend deletion votes and that post has 3 so "not enough delete votes"

@RobertLongson I'm still confused, assuming mods didn't take action there, shouldn't my flag be disputed or aged away instead of declined?

Should be, you could ask on the site meta why that's not the case.
